# Component in Slide not visible using Slider in Ionic 4 with Angular

Tags: angular, ionic4

My desired effect is to to have a different specified component load in a slide depending on the data using a switch statement.  My issue is that I do not see anything in my slides and I'm not receiving an error.  I think this may be an issue solvable by css, but when I change the components height and width too 100% I don't see anything.  I have also tried using fullscreen="true" on the component.

In my data structure I have an array of "pageType"s that I want to trigger a switch statement to open a specified angular component.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides *ngIf="pages"
    [options]="sliderConfig">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let index of pages">

  <div [ngSwitch]="index.pageType">
    <app-std-layout *ngSwitchCase="'std'" [flashCards]="index.flashCards"></app-std-layout>
    <app-std-layout *ngSwitchDefault [flashCards]="index.flashCards"></app-std-layout>
  </div>

    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

My standard layout component looks as follows~

```
<ion-content fullscreen="true">

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let flashcard of flashCards">
          <app-flashcards [flashcard]="flashcard"></app-flashcards>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Vergas Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yeah.  I marked it below.  I needed to get rid of the <ion-content> tags in my layout components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved my issue.  In `<app-std-layout>` component I need to get rid of the `<ion-content>` tags

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let flashcard of flashCards">
      <app-flashcards [flashcard]="flashcard"></app-flashcards>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I suppose `<ion-content>` tags cannot be embedded in one another.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your switch statements seem to be trying to do the same thing at the moment?

For your `app-std-layout`, in the code, do you have the `@Input()` on the `flashCards` so that pulls the information in?

Have you tried putting some normal words inside like "TEST" just to see if the component is being output?

Comment: Yeah right now I'm just trying to get my app-std-layout to work before I add more components into the switch statement.  Yeah there's an @Input.  And no, If I simply type test. it doesn't render.